# How to group Objects by property using using collector groupingBy() on top of flatMap() in Java 8

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

How to create `Map<String,List<Product>>`  of below. Here, `String` (*key* of the `Map`) is the `category` of a `Product`.

One *product* can belong to **multiple** categories, like in the example below.

I am trying with below code, however not able to get next operation:

```java
products.stream()
    .flatMap(product -> product.getCategories().stream())
    . // how should I progress from here?
```

Result should be like below:

> {electonics=[p1,p3,p4], fashion=[p1,p2,p4], kitchen=[p1,p2,p3],
> abc1=[p2], xyz1=[p3],pqr1=[p4]}

```java
Product p1 = new Product(123, Arrays.asList("electonics,fashion,kitchen".split(",")));
Product p2 = new Product(123, Arrays.asList("abc1,fashion,kitchen".split(",")));
Product p3 = new Product(123, Arrays.asList("electonics,xyz1,kitchen".split(",")));
Product p4 = new Product(123, Arrays.asList("electonics,fashion,pqr1".split(",")));
List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3, p4);
```

```java
class Product {

    int price;
    List<String> categories;

    public Product(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Product(int price, List<String> categories) {
        this.price = price;
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public List<String> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use collector `groupingBy()` for some reason, then you can define a wrapper class (*with Java 16+ a [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) would be more handy for that purpose*) which would hold a reference to a *category* and a *product* to represent every combination *category/product* which exist in the given list.

```
public record ProductCategory(String category, Product product) {}
```

Pre-Java 16 alternative:

```
public class ProductCategory {
    private String category;
    private Product product;
    
    // constructor and getters
}
```

And then in the make use of the combination of collectors `mapping()` and `toList()` as the *downstream collector* of `groupingBy()`.

```
List<Product> products = // initializing the list of products
        
Map<String, List<Product>> productsByCategory = products.stream()
    .flatMap(product -> product.getCategories().stream()
        .map(category -> new ProductCategory(category, product)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        ProductCategory::category,                   // ProductCategory::getCategory if you used a class instead of record
        Collectors.mapping(ProductCategory::product, // ProductCategory::getProduct if you used a class instead of record
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

[*A link to Online-Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/w0P)

---

But instead of creating intermediate objects and generating nested streams, the **more performant** option would be to describe the accumulation strategy within the *three-args version* of [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) (or define a *custom collector*).

That's how it might be implemented:

```
Map<String, List<Product>> productsByCategory = products.stream()
    .collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (Map<String, List<Product>> map, Product next) -> next.getCategories()
            .forEach(category -> map.computeIfAbsent(category, k -> new ArrayList<>())
                .add(next)),
        (left, right) -> right.forEach((k, v) -> 
            left.merge(k, v,(oldProd, newProd) -> { oldProd.addAll(newProd); return oldProd; }))
    );
```

[*A link to Online-Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/w0Q)

Answer (score 5):

I tried a few things and came up with the following solution:

```
Map<Object, List<Product>> result =
        products.stream()
                .flatMap(product -> product.getCategories().stream().map(p -> Map.entry(p, product)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));


System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
xyz1=[org.example.Product@15db9742], electonics=[org.example.Product@6d06d69c, org.example.Product@15db9742, org.example.Product@7852e922], abc1=[org.ex ...
```

Edit: I have seen that my solution is pretty similar to the other answer. However, my solution uses a `Map.Entry` instead of a user-defined object to bring the data into the correct shape.

Comment: *"my solution uses a Map.Entry instead of a user-defined object"* - it brings no advantage in terms of performance, and makes the code less expressive. In other words, it requires **more** effort to read because methods `getKey/getValue` are faceless, especially if code gets altered and more operations get added to the pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done with a combination of `flatMapping` and `toMap`:

```java
Map<String, List<Product>> obj = products.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.flatMapping(
            product -> product.categories().stream()
                .map(category -> Map.entry(category, List.of(product))),
            Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                (v1, v2) -> Stream.concat(v1.stream(), v2.stream()).toList()
            )
    ));
```

What happens here is that first, each `Product` is converted to a `Map.Entry<String, List<Product>>`, where the key is the category and the value is the `Product` itself, or, more precisely, a `List<Product>`, where this list initially only contains the current product.

Then you could "unpack" the map entries by using `toMap`. Of course, for those cases where the key (=category) is the same, the values (that is, the `List` with the `Product`s) must be merged.

---

Note: I used a `Map.Entry` here, but you can also write a custom class which is semantically more desirable (something like `CategoryProductsMapping(String category, List<Product> products)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that the owner inquired about groupby and flatmap, but just in case, I'll mention `reduce`.

1. I believe this is kind simple; it feels like `.collect(` method with 3 args that @Alexander Ivanchenko metioned.
2. in order to use parallelstream, you must merges two hashmaps, I don’t think it’s a good idea, there are extra iteration, I don’t think it’s useful in this case.

```
HashMap<String, List<Product>> reduce = products.stream().reduce(
        new HashMap<>(),
        (result, product) -> {
            product.getCategories().stream().distinct().forEach(
                    category -> result.computeIfAbsent(category, k -> new ArrayList<>())
                            .add(product)
            );
            return result;
        },
        (x, y) -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("does not support parallel!");
        }
);
```